# How to lower total ActiveRecord time

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord

I'm optimising my queries but I cannot understand how to lower total *ActiveRecord* time.

I have two simple queries that runs in `1.0ms` and `0.6ms`, but then ActiveRecord time is `14.3ms` which is 10 times higher then the sum of my queries. If I then add the other queries, ActiveRecord time increases exponentially.

I know ActiveRecord does some [black magic behind the scene](http://gavinmiller.io/2013/active-records-dirty-little-secret/)  so I wonder how can I lower the time spent to make it happen.

Query

```
Binda::Structure.where(slug: 'page').first.components.order('position')
```

Logs

```
Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
  Binda::Structure Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "binda_structures".* FROM "binda_structures" WHERE "binda_structures"."slug" = $1 ORDER BY "binda_structures"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["slug", "page"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Binda::Component Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "binda_components".* FROM "binda_components" WHERE "binda_components"."structure_id" = $1 ORDER BY position  [["structure_id", 2]]
  Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (15.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 118ms (Views: 42.5ms | ActiveRecord: 14.3ms)
```

#### UPDATE #1

Changing the query to following has speeded up AR time from `14.3ms` to `7.1ms` and also lowered the total time from `118ms` to `39ms`. Sweet!

```rb
id = Binda::Structure.where( slug: 'page' ).pluck(:id)
Binda::Component.where( structure_id: id ).order( 'position' )
```

```sh
Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "binda_structures"."id" FROM "binda_structures" WHERE "binda_structures"."slug" = $1  [["slug", "page"]]
  Rendering pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Binda::Component Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "binda_components".* FROM "binda_components" WHERE "binda_components"."structure_id" = 2 ORDER BY position
  Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (20.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 39ms (Views: 29.4ms | ActiveRecord: 7.1ms)
```

#### UPDATE #2

As mentioned by Max in comments it's also possible to reduce the request to a single query. The difference with the previous solution isn't huge (`32ms` from `39ms`).

```rb
Binda::Component.where( structure_id: Binda::Structure.where( slug: 'page' ) ).order( 'position' )
```

```sh
Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
  Rendering pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Binda::Component Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "binda_components".* FROM "binda_components" WHERE "binda_components"."structure_id" IN (SELECT "binda_structures"."id" FROM "binda_structures" WHERE "binda_structures"."slug" = $1) ORDER BY position  [["slug", "page"]]
  Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 32ms (Views: 27.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Comment: Retrieving the data is only part of the cost. Converting those rows into ActiveRecord models can be expensive.

Comment: If you add a composite index for structure_id and position you should see an improvement as the number of records increase.

Comment: `Binda::Component.where(structure_id: Binda::Structure.where(slug: 'page' ).order('position')` - will create a single query.

Comment: @max, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't exactly clear what is consuming this much time. The `42.5ms` and `14.3ms` don't add up to `118ms`.

You need to find the bottleneck in your code. Try calling the `to_sql` method after your Active record statement. Then execute that query directly against your database.

Rule out different things. Maybe try initializing a single instance of this model to see if that is slow. Are you running any complex initialization routines or AR callbacks? Are there outbound network calls laced into the model somewhere?

Comment: I'm going to try `to_sql` method and benchmark the ActiveRecord callback I have. I'm sure is going to be a bloodbath `>_<`!

Comment: I changed the query avoiding the helper generated by the `has_many` association and this drop AR time by 50% and total time by 75%. See *update* in my question.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got things sped up

Answer (score 0):

I see the "high" AR timing as a reminder that abstractions such as ORM and AR come at a price, hence inefficiency, in mapping what the application wants to do versus what a RBBMS needs to do.